# Cassandra datastax driver times out on a too big a query

Tags: python, pandas, datastax, cassandra-2.0

This query is fine, but if I change the amount of time to get data back, I get the error below (over 200,000 rows). I am not sure if it is the query or the fill/resample operations that are the problem. I only have one machine in the cluster.

```
rsltES = session.execute( """SELECT * FROM tickdata.timeseries  
    WHERE 
    curve = 0 
    AND symbol = 1000
    AND time > '2016-05-23T08:00:00-0400'
    AND time < '2016-05-25T19:00:00-0400'
    order by time
    allow filtering;""")

dfes = dfes.set_index(['time'])
dfes.index.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
df_ohlcES = dfes.resample('5Min').ohlc()
df_ohlcES = df_ohlcES.ffill()
df_ohlcES['DateTime'] = np.arange(len(df_ohlcES))

# Move the DateTime Column to the Front
colsES = df_ohlcES.columns
colsES = colsES[-1:] | colsES[:-1]
df_ohlcES = df_ohlcES[colsES]
```

If a query returns too much data, the query times out. Is there a way to increase the timeout?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandascas.py", line 36, in <module>
    allow filtering;""")
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1647, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:28041)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3243, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:61954)
cassandra.ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a server-side read timeout set in [cassandra.yaml](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0/conf/cassandra.yaml#L513-L514). That requires a server setting and restart.

If you're really getting too many rows, you might also try reducing the [fetch_size](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.Statement.fetch_size) to make requested pages smaller.

You might also want to find out if your workload has frequent overwrites -- a condition that can result in many tombstones that cause slow reads. One empirical inspection you can do is to raise that timeout and turn on [tracing](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute) to see what's taking so long.

Answer (score 1):

Timeout on database is by default 2 seconds. What you can do instead of increasing this timeout is to use fetchSize and fetch results in chunks. Bear in mind that allow filtering is a bad bad practice and its basically a full table search hitting all nodes in the cluster and thats probably whats causing you a timeout even tho you are not querying millions of rows.